# Can't find the XPath selector of an element that only has unique siblings

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to find in Selenium Webdriver an element with the XPath selector `"//span[@class='v-treegrid-expander collapsed']"` shown in the screenshot below which has a unique sibling with the XPath selector `"//div[contains(@class, 'v-treegrid-cell-content') and contains(text(), 'QA-images')]"` and while both elements separately can be searched in the DOM by the mentioned selectors, when I try to combine them and create a selector that searches for my element `"//div[contains(@class, 'v-treegrid-cell-content') and contains(text(), 'QA-images')]"` having a sibling `"//div[contains(@class, 'v-treegrid-cell-content') and contains(text(), 'QA-images')]"` then this new selector doesn't work

[image]

This is the item I want to catch but there are 10 of the same on the page:

```
<span class="v-treegrid-expander collapsed" style=""></span>
```

So I want to use to create an XPath selector sibling of this element that is:

```
<div class="gwt-HTML v-treegrid-cell-content"><span class="v-table-icon-element icon-folder"></span>QA-files</div>
```

This is one of the XPath selectors I tested for this purpose but without success:

```
"//span[@class='v-treegrid-expander collapsed']/following-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'v-treegrid-cell-content') and contains(text(), 'QA-images')]"
```

Where am I making a mistake or what is another way to find this element using the fact that it has a unique sibling containing the mentioned text?

Comment: Please add the code in your question instead of image. You can use ``` before and after the code to format it. [More formatting information here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Can you update the question with the text based HTML rather than image?

Comment: @Ar2r if you are hesitant to put link of the page, you add relevant portion of the element as text instead of image. You can copy element from dev-tools Elements tab -> `Right Click` -> `Copy` -> `Copy Element`

Comment: Sure, I just added the code under the image, if there is still something missing please let me know

Comment: Copy and add the element with class `v-treegrid-node` in multiline using ```

Comment: @DanielSabrel
<div class="v-treegrid-node depth-0"><span class="v-treegrid-expander collapsed"></span><div class="gwt-HTML v-treegrid-cell-content"><span class="v-table-icon-element icon-folder"></span>QA-images</div></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that the contains-function accepts as it's first argument 1 string.

If you use `contains(text(), 'QA-images')]"` as in your example, you must be certain that there is only `one` text()-node , otherwise it fails.
In the case where there are probably more, you can better use the `.` that tells the engine to first combine all text inside the context-node, and use that for the contains-function.

You have several options:

```
//div[div[contains(@class, 'v-treegrid-cell-content') and contains(., 'QA-files')]]/span
```

This will first select the container div that has a div with the unique properties and get there it's child span. No other predicates are needed on the span I suppose.

or

```
//div[contains(@class, 'v-treegrid-cell-content') and contains(., 'QA-files')]/preceding-sibling::span
```

This will select the unique container div preceding-sibling::span.

Comment: The first selector worked correctly and did its job and in the case of the second one I got an error ".... is not a valid XPath expression."

Comment: There was a error in the second one. I corrected it

Answer (score 1):

I see that your text is QA-files and not QA-images.

Can you try to find div, which next span contains class `v-treegrid-expander collapsed` and then go down to div that contains text QA-files.

`//div[./div[contains(@class, 'v-treegrid-cell-content') and contains(., 'QA-files')]]//span[contains(@class, 'v-treegrid-expander collapsed')]`

Probably, it should work. If it does not - please, provide be part of your DOM in HTML format.

Comment: With this selector, it locates this element  "<div class="gwt-HTML v-treegrid-cell-content"><span class="v-table-icon-element icon-folder"></span>QA-files</div>
so an element that is a sibling to the element I am looking for "<span class="v-treegrid-expander collapsed" style=""></span>"

Answer (score 1):

Try the below XPATH expression:

```
//div[contains(text(),'QA-files')]//preceding::span[@class='v-treegrid-expander collapsed']
```

**Explanation:**

- `//div[contains(text(),'QA-files')]` - first locate the `<div>` node
- `//preceding::` - this is used to locate all preceding nodes to current node
- `//preceding::span[@class='v-treegrid-expander collapsed']` - This will basically locate the preceding `<span>` node which has `class=v-treegrid-expander collapsed`

**UPDATE:**

```
(//div[contains(text(),'QA-files')]//preceding::span[@class='v-treegrid-expander collapsed'])[n]
```

`n` - being the number of elements it locates

Comment: Using this selector "//div[contains(text(),'QA-files')]//preceding::span[@class='v-treegrid-expander collapsed']" finds me the first "<span class="v-treegrid-expander collapsed"></span>" element in the list instead of the one with the required text

Comment: Check the updated answer. Right click --> Inspect Element and press Ctrl+F on the Elements console. Place the following XPath - `//div[text()='QA-files1']//preceding::span[@class='v-treegrid-expander collapsed']`. Check the number of elements it locates. Give that value as `n`

Comment: ]//preceding::span : the double slash is redundant. preceding::span will select every span before the current context, not only it’s sibling nodes

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed - Didn't understand your comment. Where in my XPath expression did you find `preceding::span`? Do you mind giving more explanation on your comment?

Comment: You are using `preceding::span` at several places in your answer. Double slash (`//`) means use any descendant. And preceding::span means any span before the current-node in de xml-tree. In this example i.e. also before the current `div`, before the current `td`, before the current `tr`, before the current `table`. etc.

Comment: I am not using `preceding::span`, but using `preceding::span[@class='v-treegrid-expander collapsed']`. So this should locate only those `span` which has attribute `class=v-treegrid-expander collapsed`. Also, if you see the XPath expression in my updated answer, it will locate just the previous `span` to the current node. Do you agree?